# Query on nodejs shows different result , while in phpyadmin exact what i want

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have following mysql query

```
SELECT c.`id`
    ,c.`category_name`
    ,c.`category_type`
    ,c.bookmark_count
    ,f.category_id cat_id
    ,f.unfollow_at
    ,(CASE
        WHEN c.id = f.follower_category_id THEN (SELECT count(`user_bookmarks`.`id`)
                                               FROM `user_bookmarks`
                                               WHERE (`user_bookmarks`.`category_id` = cat_id )
                                                   AND `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` NOT IN (SELECT `bookmark_id`
                                                                                             FROM `user_deleted_bookmarks`
                                                                                             WHERE user_id = 18 )
                                                                                                 AND ((`f`.`created_at` >= `user_bookmarks`.`created_at`)))
        ELSE 0 END ) counter
    , c.id
    , f.follower_category_id follow_id
    , c.user_id
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN following_follower_categories f ON f.follower_category_id = c.id
WHERE c.user_id = 18
    AND c.id NOT IN (SELECT `category_id`
                     FROM `user_deleted_categories`
                     WHERE `user_id` = 18 )
ORDER BY `category_name` ASC
```

Which is working fine in phpmyadmin. 
But when  i am using same query in nodejs

by

```
var sqlnew = "SELECT c.`id`,c.`category_name`,c.`category_type` ,c.bookmark_count ,f.category_id cat_id , f.unfollow_at ,\n\
                    (CASE WHEN c.id = f.follower_category_id THEN (SELECT count(`user_bookmarks`.`id`) FROM `user_bookmarks` WHERE \n\
                    (`user_bookmarks`.`category_id` = cat_id) AND `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` NOT IN (SELECT `bookmark_id` \n\
                    FROM `user_deleted_bookmarks` WHERE user_id = "+user_id+" ) AND ((`f`.`created_at` >= `user_bookmarks`.`created_at`))) ELSE 0 END) counter ,\n\
                    c.id , f.follower_category_id follow_id , c.user_id FROM categories c LEFT JOIN following_follower_categories f ON f.follower_category_id = c.id \n\
                    WHERE c.user_id = "+user_id+"   AND  c.id NOT IN (SELECT `category_id` FROM `user_deleted_categories` WHERE `user_id` = "+user_id+" ) ORDER BY `category_name` ASC";

    connection.query(sqlnew, function(err, res) {
     if(!err){
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)));
    }

});
```

this is showing different results to me. Any idea. i checked , i am using same database.

Thanks

Comment: Provide us the code where you declare the `sqlnew` variable

Comment: Thank you, why have you these `\n\\` in your query?

Comment: Because i cannot add query in one line. Anyways what query i  wrote in phpmyadmin, i just get it from console